# Existence of Weak solution of a PDE with singular term

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

On the paper "[On the Cauchy Problem for Reaction-Diffusion Equations](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1993-337-02/S0002-9947-1993-1153016-5/S0002-9947-1993-1153016-5.pdf)" Wang studies the Hardy-Hénon equation
$$
\begin{cases}
u_t -  \Delta u =  |\cdot|^{l}u^{p}& \mbox{ in } \mathbb{R}^n \times (0,T), \\  
{u}(0) =  {u}_{0}& \mbox{ in } \mathbb{R}^n \\
\end{cases}.
$$
The notion of a weak solution is often mentioned, and it is established that Mild solutions are weak solutions. I would like to know if it is possible to show directly for this equation the existence of a weak solution, in the sense
$$ \int u\phi dx\left|_{0}^{T}\right. = \int_{0}^{T} \int[u (\Delta\phi + \partial_t \phi) + |\cdot|^{l}u^{p}\phi] dxds$$
Is there any way to show this existence, even with this singular term? Can you reference any papers for reading? I even think of Galerkin's method, but that singular term seems to get in the way.